# Jenkins Pipeline build job on user-specified agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have used Labels to achieve the Job Build on User-specified agent. I'm passing Label as a parameter from Pipeline to downstream JOB A.

Problem statement : 
If I don't specify a "Label" value to the Job, it should build job on any node that is available or be inqueue for the next available node.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What type of job is JOB A (freestyle, scripted pipeline, declarative pipeline, etc)?

Comment: JOB A is a freestyle project @kskid19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark all your nodes with a "default" label, in addition to any specific label.

Check whether a variable has been passed, and if no use the default label.

If a label parameter has been passed, your job will build on any available node with that label; otherwise the "default" label will be selected, and the job will build on any available node with a default label.